# gradlew doesn't work with Podman on MacOS M2

Tags: macos, gradle, podman

I run `./gradlew` within container image `gradle:7.4-jdk8` on MacOS (M2) with Podman and got an error

```
mmap failed for CEN and END part of zip file
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
```

Command:

```
podman run --rm -it --userns=keep-id:uid=1000,gid=1000 -v $(pwd):/app -w /app gradle:7.4-jdk8 bash
./gradlew cleanTest test --no-daemon
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had the same problem. do you fine solution?

Comment: Nope, I started it on a remote CI runner

Comment: I had resolve my problem with could not find or load main class. some how with Mac m2 using Adopejdk it has some change interm of exec java command with -classpath. by changing the command It load okay.